# $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2+3}{x^4+1}\,dx$ via contour integration?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, solution-verification, contour-integration

I want to calculate  $\displaystyle I=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2+3}{x^4+1}\;dx$ using contour integration.

I've obtained the correct answer of $I=\sqrt{2}\pi$ below, but I would appreciate if someone could verify my proof.

---

Let $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{z^2+3}{z^4+1}$; and let $C$ be the semicircle with boundary diameter on the real line (say from $-R$ to $R$) in the upper half plane. Now, $f(z)$ has four simple poles at $z = \pm i^{\frac{1}{2}}, \pm i^{\frac{3}{2}}$. The two poles at $z =  i^{\frac{1}{2}},  i^{\frac{3}{2}}$ lie on the upper half plane, and the sum of the residues of $f$ at these poles is $-\sqrt{2}i$.

So $$\displaystyle \oint_C f(z)\,dz=\int_{-R}^{R} f(z) \, dz +\int_{\text{Arc}} f(z)\, {dz} $$

So by the Residue theorem $$-i\sqrt{2}\cdot 2i\pi=\int_{-R}^{R} f(z) \, dz +\int_{\text{Arc}} f(z)\, {dz} $$

Thus $$2\sqrt{2}\pi=\int_{-R}^{R} f(z) \, dz +\int_{\text{Arc}} f(z)\, {dz} $$

---

I tried to show that the arc integral goes to $0$ as follows

$$\bigg|\int_{\text{Arc}} f(z)\, {dz} \bigg| \le  \int_{\text{Arc}} |f(z)|\, {dz} \le \frac{R^2-3}{R^4-1} \cdot \pi R \to 0,  ~\text{as} ~ R \to \infty $$

Because $|z|^4=\left|z^4\right| = \left|z^4+1-1\right| \le \left|z^4+1\right|+1  $

So $\displaystyle |{z^4+1}| \le |z|^4-1 = R^4-1 $, similarly

$|z|^2 = |z^2+3-3| \le |z^2+3|+3 \implies |z^2+3|\le |z|^2-3 = R^2-3 $

And the length of the arc is $\pi R$ combining altogether we get

$$\displaystyle \bigg|\int_{\text{arc}}\frac{z^2+3}{z^4+1} \,d{z}\bigg|  \le \frac{(R^2-3)\cdot \pi R }{R^4-1}$$

Which goes to zero as $R \to \infty$. So the arc integral goes to $0$ as $R \to 0$.

---

Therefore $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{z^2+3}{z^4+1}\,{dz} = 2\sqrt{2}\pi $ so that $I = \sqrt{2}\pi$ since the integrand is even.

Is this correct?

Comment: Minor nitpick, it should be $R^2+3$ in the numerator. Everything else looks good.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Many thanks for going through this. I see the mistake. It should have been  $|z^2+3| \le |z^2|+3 = R^2+3$ (triangle inequality).

Comment: Instead of "So $\displaystyle |{z^4+1}| \le |z|^4-1 = R^4-1 $" should be "So $\displaystyle |{z^4+1}| \ge |z|^4-1 = R^4-1 $". This is OK because $\displaystyle |{z^4+1}| $ is in de denominator.

Comment: I suggest the easier explanation $$\left|\frac{z^2+3}{z^4+1}\right| = \frac 1{|z|^2}\left|\frac{1+3/z^2}{1+1/z^4}\right|$$The last factor $\to 1$ as $|z| \to \infty$ and is continuous for $|z|\ge 1$, so it is bounded by some $M$. I.e. $|f(z)| < \frac M{R^2}$ for $|z| \ge R \ge 1$